# Add custom buttom instead of default button in facebook sdk

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new in ios developing so I want to add Custome a button which is used to login into the facebook not using default button in FACEBOOK sdk's Button..

Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/) on step 1, you can use a normal UIButton for the login, so you simply have to add style to that button.
Eg:

```
UIButton *login_button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[login_button setFrame:CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0)];
[login_button setTitle:@"Login!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[login_button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[login_button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:login_button];
```

Comment: I want to login into facebook using that button dear... @Alberto Vitale.

Comment: I edited the answer. Check it! (if I understood the question)

Comment: Yes you understood the question but i m trying to do this for ios-5 so how can i do for this in iOS-5 ???